# for-if without list comprehension in one line

Tags: python, list-comprehension

can this be written in one line without List Comprehensions?

```
for x in vec: 
    if x > 3:
         ...
         ...
```

Comment: Why not? / Why 1 line?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with them, but would a `lambda` statement be appropriate here?

Comment: @blender: A `lambda` alone would be nonsense. As predicate for `i-/filter`, yes.

Comment: Depends what you mean by "this". What criteria does it have to fulfill in order to be considered equivalent to the code you gave? Obviously 100% equivalence would mean it took more than one line.

Comment: If x is a large word, I have to type it twice. I was wondering if there is a way to add a condition to the loop directly

Comment: Also, does the one line include the statements inside the "if", or just the for and the if?

Comment: *I have to type it twice*, I'm so glad you've demonstrating why I voted to close this question.

Comment: I didnt know the intention of the programmer changes the value of the question. Indeed the value is in the content, not in the intention.

Comment: Note that the clean way to do this is not to stuff the condition into a lambda or an awkward generator expression; just say `for x in vec: if x <= 3: continue; ...`.  "Do it in one line" is rarely an appropriate design constraint.

Answer (score 3):

**No, you can't**. The [Python language reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html) states:

> Compound statements consist of one or
>   more ‘clauses.’ A clause consists of a
>   header and a ‘suite.’ The clause
>   headers of a particular compound
>   statement are all at the same
>   indentation level. Each clause header
>   begins with a uniquely identifying
>   keyword and ends with a colon. A suite
>   is a group of statements controlled by
>   a clause. A suite can be one or more
>   semicolon-separated simple statements
>   on the same line as the header,
>   following the header’s colon, or it
>   can be one or more indented statements
>   on subsequent lines. **Only the latter
>   form of suite can contain nested
>   compound statements;** the following is
>   illegal, mostly because it wouldn’t be
>   clear to which if clause a following
>   else clause would belong:

```
if test1: if test2: print x
```

Indeed, Python generates a `SyntaxError` for the nested ifs above. More formally regarding `for`, this is its grammar in Python:

```
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]

suite         ::=  stmt_list NEWLINE | NEWLINE INDENT statement+ DEDENT

stmt_list     ::=  simple_stmt (";" simple_stmt)* [";"]
```

Note that when `for` is followed by a statement without an indentation, that statement must be a `stmt_list`, which only allows `simple_stmt` instances. `simple_stmt` is this:

```
simple_stmt ::=  expression_stmt
                 | assert_stmt
                 | assignment_stmt
                 | augmented_assignment_stmt
                 | pass_stmt
                 | del_stmt
                 | print_stmt
                 | return_stmt
                 | yield_stmt
                 | raise_stmt
                 | break_stmt
                 | continue_stmt
                 | import_stmt
                 | global_stmt
                 | exec_stmt
```

Which doesn't include compound statements like `if` and `for`.

---

That said, keep in mind that Python's syntax is aimed at clarity. Therefore it's better not to nest such statements, this is what generators/list comprehensions were made for. If you deem your computation to be simple enough for a single line, then comprehensions are for you. Otherwise, you really don't want to clutter the code by having everything on a single line - break it up nicely with indentation. A few extra lines don't cost much these days.

Comment: I don't think he was asking if he could put those 2 statements on one line.  I think he just wants the overall effect of those 2 statements to occur on one line.

Comment: @Eli: Since he put two lines of ellipsis in the example, he's propably doing something procedural with `x`, rendering list comprehensions an inacceptable solution. **List comprehensions are not a way to turn any loop into a single oneliner**.

Comment: @delnan: you could be right, I don't really know. Isn't OP-intention-interpretation a fun SO game? :-) I encourage Roberto to clarify what he really wants

Comment: read again, functional if was introduced some time ago in python syntax. What you show is just that you can't do it using the if *statement*. There is other ways, there is even several ways to do it... look at the other answers...

Comment: @kriss: my answer refers to the direct question of whether it's possible to write nested statements like the OP originally asked. You can't. Yes, there are other ways to achieve the same effect, but compound statements simply can't be nested this way on a single line. Personally I found this educational - I had no idea this is the case before doing some research for this answer. Although I would probably not write code like this anyway, it's interesting to know nevertheless. You may disagree - it's your right, of course.

Comment: This is wordily incorrect.  He didn't say anything about using only core language syntax.  The correct answer is yes, using a generator function like `ifilter` to do the filtering.

Comment: Wow, I'm really surprised at what's going on here. Never would've imagined this would turn out to be my most downvoted answer on SO!

Answer (score 3):

See @KennyTM... no reason to compress that much.

What being said, `for x in (i in vec if i > 3)` does the job, as well as `itertools.ifilter` (or just the builtin `filter` in Python 3) with a `lambda x: x > 3` predicate. They work with all iterables as well, and are lazy (e.g. if you `break` during the loop, you didn't check a single item too much).

Comment: The whole point, as the OP stated in a comment, is that “if *x* is a large word, I have to type it twice” (hair-pulling moment), so probably a `filter`+`lambda` is the appropriate answer for this… question.

Answer (score 0):

It can, but list comprehensions/generator expressions are the exact sort of thing that should be used here.  Depending on what you want to do in your `if` block, you could use some form of `map` or `reduce`, but list comprehensions and generator expressions are likely the best way to do it.

Comment: I need to write several lines after the if, so that isnt going to fly

Comment: @Roberto so write a function that does what you need and use that in the list comprehension

Comment: then I remove a line for the for/if everytime I have to do something like that, but I add one line for declaring the function :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes

for x in filter(lambda i:i>3,vec):

Comment: Note that in Python 2, this will instantly create a new list, instead of generating the values lazily.

Answer (score -1):

You can imagine somethings like this :

```
def do_something(value):
    ...

def do_otherthing(value):
    ...


for x in t: do_something(x) if x>3 else do_otherthing(x)
```

Comment: that's exactly what he didn't ask for:  "without List Comprehensions"

Comment: The question specifically doesn't ask for this - propably because the `...` are several statements, in which case a list comprehension would be non-idiomatic.

Comment: I changed my answer, even if you can do a limited things with the part after the for statement....

Comment: @delnan @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: why downvote ? He did it using functional if and it works fine..

Comment: Maybe because the OP asked if it could be written in 1 line.

Comment: From the Title: "in one line"