# Enumerate on specific items of a list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, enumerate

Let `L = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 5]`. Do you know why this works in Python :

```
for idx in [idx for idx, item in enumerate(L) if item == 1]:
   dosomething(idx)      # idx = 0, 3, 4
```

but this doesn't :

```
for idx, item in enumerate(L) if item == 1:
   dosomething(idx)
```

?

Comment: Well, because list comprehensions allow us to use if-else conditions in the loop.

Comment: Because there's no syntax for the second approach.

Comment: because the former uses the `[, if <filter>]` optional grammar of comprehensions, and the latter just isn't valid.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is asking *why* the language grammar doesn't allow this.  Why-not questions about motivation can often be too opinion-based to work, but OTOH sometimes people dig up good reasons, historical references, and/or dev discussions to settle the issue.

Comment: This answer explains, with reference to the Python language reference and with some details about the actual syntax in question, more about why this construction isn't valid: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4226532/1858225

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have a conditional in your for loop like that, it's a syntax error.

It would have to be inside the loop like so:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(L):
    if item == 1:
        dosomething(idx)
```

Your first example is a list comprehension, and your list comprehension is syntactically sound.

As an aside, you can use an `if` and an `else` in the same list comprehension, but the syntax changes around a little, like so:

```
list_comp = [x if *condition* else y for x in z]
```

More info on list comprehensions [here](http://blog.cdleary.com/2010/04/learning-python-by-example-list-comprehensions/), [here](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/lists/list-comprehensions-in-python/) and Google ;)

**EDIT:**

Since this has been accepted as the answer, I will also include here, for completeness, the link that `@Kyle Strand` posted in the comments with regards to the actual reasons(under the hood) that the `for/if` syntax in your question is invalid.

[for-if without list comprehension in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226523/for-if-without-list-comprehension-in-one-line/4226532#4226532)